# Cross compile google v8 library for raspberry pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, v8

I am having a problem with cross compiling google v8 libraries for raspberry pi, and constantly getting "Illegal instruction" error when compiling official sample from site. These are the steps i followed:

1. Downloaded cross compile https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/
2. Cloned v8 git https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git
3. Exported CXX LINK point to `arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` from cross compile tools.
4. run `make arm.release armv7=false hardfp=on snapshot=off armfpu=vfp armfloatabi=hard -j5`
5. Copied generated executable `shell` and `d8` from out/arm.release directory to pi (Raspbian kernel version 3.6.11) and it WORKS.
   These steps prove that cross compilation toolchain is functional.

Problem occurs when trying to run other cross-compiled software that is linked to v8 libraries. For example sample code from https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started#intro.
Code is cross-compiled with this command (same as example, just changed compiler)

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -I. hello_world.cc -o hello_world -Wl,--start-group out/x64.release/obj.target/{tools/gyp/libv8_{base,libbase,snapshot,libplatform},third_party/icu/libicu{uc,i18n,data}}.a -Wl,--end-group -lrt -pthread
```

When i copy that code to pi and run it i get SIGILL (Illegal instruction).

Note: cross compiled software that doesn't use v8 libraries works fine. Also x64 v8 libraries on host computer work fine.

On newer kernel versions `shell` and `d8` were also throwing SIGILL but than i switched to older version 3.6.11 (problems with newer kernel https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/IPT9EeYK9bg) and they started working, but compiled sample code is still showed same issues.

Did anyone have similar experience? Any suggestion on how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution thanks to post on v8 google group. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/LTppUbqNrzI

Problem was in make arguments it should be.

```
make arm arm_version=6 armfpu=vfp armfloatabi=hard
```